# When does cronjob start running?

Tags: cron, cron-task

I have this line for my cronjob

it's supposed to run every 2 hours

after running `crontab -e`
I saved this line

```
0 */2 * * * /Documents/scrapping/run.py
```

I was expecting the cronjob to start immediately after saving the file and then repeat every 2 hours

but when I saved the file- the script/cronjob wasnt running?

when is the cronjob being executed based on my script?

Comment: http://www.cronmaker.com/

Comment: thanks-  when i select every 2 hours -when is it supposed to run the first time?

Comment: and the format is wrong on cronmaker- under cron format it says 0 0 0/2 1/1 * ? *

Comment: crontab guru works better- but i figuered it out when it starts thanks dude

Comment: Glad you solved it! :)

Comment: @charliebrown can you post your findings as an answer or comment?

Comment: my problem hasnt solved yet- its not running- i first thought it will start at 10 pm but it never started